# Facebook - Cannot disable sandbox mode after Privacy Policies update

Tags: facebook, sandbox

After a few Facebook alerts about my app lacking privacy policies (totally forgot about it and the email address was not my own), my app was taken down. So, I updated the apps Privacy Policy and ToS, saved changes and tried to disable sandbox mode so my app became visible again.

Nothing happened.

It keeps showing me an error message: [image: Error message]

Is there something I might be doing wrong? The Privacy Policy URL and ToS URL are the only things I changed, and the app worked fine before.

Thanks in advance

### UPDATE

It is not a problem with the privacy policy update, but with the basic app settings. Whe I try saving the app without removing sandbox mode, it still shows me the error. Has anything changed since, or the Facebook service is having problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Facebook no longer accepted the tilde (~) as a valid url character.